# ASP.NET Datasource Select Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, sqldatasource

I have a local DB table that is displayed in a `GridView`. In that table, I have a column called: "Completed".

When I first display the table, I am displaying it without completed records (Completed=false).  Here is the `SqlDataSource` select command:

```
"SELECT * FROM [CERecord] WHERE [Completed]='false' ORDER BY [Priority]";
```

I have a checkbox which causes postback. I want to toggle the display of Completed records by ticking / unticking it:

```
protected void cbShowCompletedRecords_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbShowCompletedRecords.Checked)
            CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CERecord] ORDER BY [Priority]";
        else
        {
            CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CERecord] WHERE [Completed]='false' ORDER BY [Priority]";
        }
    }
```

Currently, when I check the box, I get all the records.  But when I uncheck it, the `GridView` doesn't update, even though the code above executes. What I am missing?

Comment: Try using the `Rebind` method after the `if..else` block
`Grid.Rebind()`

Comment: what type is Completed in DB? bool or string?

Comment: @Ron Do you mean `DataBind();`?

Comment: I have already tried `CEDatabaseSource.DataBind()` and it doesn't change anything. Completed is bool in the db (well bit).

Comment: So why isn't your where clause `WHERE [Completed]=0`?

Comment: Thanks Ron. I was missing the gridview.databind alright. That fixed it.

Comment: My bad.. it was `Databind()`

Comment: @Ron No worries.  You should post that as an answer, it sounds like you helped sd_dracula out!

Comment: @jadarnel27 - Thanks.. I posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using your `GridView`s `DataBind` method after the `if...else` block

```
protected void cbShowCompletedRecords_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbShowCompletedRecords.Checked)
            CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CERecord] ORDER BY [Priority]";
        else
        {
            CEDatabaseSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CERecord] WHERE [Completed]='false' ORDER BY [Priority]";
        }

        yourGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

This will make sure the results shown in your grid reflect the changes you made to the select statement.

Comment: Added some more context, and an explanation of the solution.  You should always try to post as complete of an answer as you can.  It will help future visitors more, and help you get more upvotes =)

Answer (score 1):

The SqlDataSource allows you to bind parameters to control properties:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="myds" runat="server" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CERecord] WHERE [Completed]=:COMPLETED ORDER BY [Priority]">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="MyCheckbox" Name="COMPLETED" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This will modify your select command according to the "Checked" property of your checkbox.

Comment: That is not quite the logic the OP is looking for. They either want all records, or just uncompleted records. Very good point about the ControlParameters, though.

Comment: Also, that syntax looks a little funky. Does `[Completed]=:COMPLETED` work? I've always used `[Completed]=@COMPLETED`.

Comment: @jadarnel27: sorry, I misread the question, thanks for pointing this out. By the way, I always used the `:` syntax and it worked for me...

Answer (score -1):

If Completed is bit type in DB change your query to:

```
"SELECT * FROM [CERecord] WHERE [Completed]=0 ORDER BY [Priority]";
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question, but it is better to practice to write your query this way @sd_dracula.